# Marie simulator multiplication of three numbers

Tags: assembly, marie

In Marie simulator, how would I multiply 3 positive numbers (Ex. 21 19 and 23) and store the result to a variable **product** using a loop? I'm new to Marie and can't figure this out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I used two variables Sum1 and Sum2 for the iterations.  Sum1 adds the first variable by the count of the second variable. This total is then added by the count of the third variable. The result at the end is your `product`.

For example:
2 x 3 x 4
2 + 2 + 2 = 6 (`Sum1` add 2, 3 times)
6 + 6 + 6 + 6 = 24 (`Sum2` add 6, 4 times)

```
    Input
    Store   A
    Input
    Store   B
    Input
    Store   C

    Load    B
    Store   Count   /Set count for B times

Loop1,  Load    A
    Add     Sum1
    Output  /Track process
    Store   Sum1

    Load    Count
    Subt    One
    Store   Count
    Skipcond 800
    Jump    Count2
    Jump    Loop1

Count2, Load    C
    Store   Count   /Set count for C times

Loop2,  Load    Sum1
    Add     Sum2
    Store   Sum2    /Final Sum2 == Product
    Output  /Track process
    Load    Count
    Subt    One
    Store   Count
    Skipcond 800
    Jump    End
    Jump    Loop2

End,    Load    Sum2
    Output
    Halt

A,  Dec 0
B,  Dec 0
C,  Dec 0
Sum1,   Dec 0
Sum2,   Dec 0
Count,  Dec 0
One,    Dec 1
```